# Why my spark streaming app does not show any out put

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

This is my follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174347/how-to-evaluate-spark-dstream-objects-with-an-spark-data-frame) from my earlier stack overflow question ,for which I did not get a response

I have tried writing this ,which does not throw up any error but it does not show any out put

My goal is to evaluate the Dstream objects with historical data RDD ,I could not

find any example for pyspark like this ( checking streaming RDD with static RDD

created before hand ) .Appreciate your response . Thanks

```
"""
Created on Thu May 05 16:23:15 2016

@author: bghosh
"""
import re
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,functions as func,Row


sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "realtimeApp")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,10)
files = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://RealTimeInputFolder/")

########Lets get the data from the db which is relavant for streaming ###

driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
dataurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://devserver:1433"
db = "devDB"
table = "stream_helper"
credential = "dev_credential"

########basic data for evaluation purpose ########

#base_data = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(driver=driver,url=dataurl,database=db,user=credential,password=credential,dbtable=table).load()

base_data = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(driver=driver,url=dataurl,database=db,user=credential,password=credential,dbtable=table).load()
base_data.registerTempTable("base_data")

######
files_count = files.flatMap(lambda file: file.split( ))

#pattern =  '(TranAmount=Decimal.{2})(.[0-9]*.[0-9]*)(\\S+ )(TranDescription=u.)([a-zA-z\\s]+)([\\S\\s]+ )(dSc=u.)([A-Z]{2}.[0-9]+)'


tranfiles = "wasb://vanspark01@vanspark01.blob.core.windows.net/RealTimeInputFolder01/"

def getSqlContextInstance(sparkContext):
    if ('sqlContextSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance'] = SQLContext(sparkContext)
    return globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance']

def preparse(logline):
    #match = re.search(pattern,logline)
    pre = logline.split(",")


    return(
    Row(
    Customer_id = pre[-1],
    trantype = pre[-4],
    amount = float(pre[-5]))
    )



def parse():
    parsed_tran = ssc.textFileStream(tranfiles).map(preparse)
    #success = parsed_tran.filter(lambda s: s[1] == 1).map(lambda x:x[0])

    #fail = parsed_tran.filter(lambda s:s[1] == 0).map(lambda x:x[0])
    """if fail.count() > 0:
        print "no of non parsed file : %d",fail.count()
    """
    return parsed_tran#success


def check_historic(rdd):

    #checking with the historical table #
    try:
        streamSqlcontext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd)
        stream_df = streamSqlcontext.createDataFrame(rdd)
        stream_df.registerTempTable("stream_df")
        result_data_frame = streamSqlcontext.sql("select * from stream_df LEFT OUTER JOIN base_data on stream_df.Customer_id= base_data.Customer_id"  )
        result_data_frame.show()

    except:
        pass
    #return result_data_frame.rdd


success = parse()

success.foreachRDD(check_historic)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Can anybody pls assist me in this :(